# how to remove the time stamp in a contract end date in an email template

Tags: formula-field, contracts

I Would like to have a Date Format in an email template for the contract end date.Based on the requirement im using the enddate in an html email template but its displaying the date and time ,but we would like to have only the date displayed.How can i do this.

In Contrac End Date ...its displaying the date and time .But i would like to have only the Date Displayed.

```
Contract End Date :2016-08-28 00:00:00
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: try this DATEVALUE(somefieldname)

Comment: @kurunve:Thanks for your response.I tried creating with teh DateValue.It didnt work.Any suggestions very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below formula in the Email Template to get Date Format as DD/MM/YYYY

Contract End Date: {!MID(TEXT(Contract End Date), 9, 2)&"/"&MID(TEXT(Contract End Date), 6, 2)&"/"&LEFT(TEXT(Contract End Date), 4)}

Incase you want hyphen(-) instead of forward slash(/) remove (/) and replace with (-) for date to appear as DD-MM-YYYY.

Comment: :Thanks for your response.Small Concern ,the contract end dates differ for all the contracts.so if i use this formula ,will it work for all the different contracts end date.Because the one given in post is an example.I just wanna remove the time stamp and the display the date.Can you let me know how does it works when we use {!MID(TEXT(Contract End Date), 9, 2) ,it displays the date and how does it calculate.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: yes it will work for for all contract end dates. Basically it takes the Date and then formats it into DD/MM/YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY. You can even move the pieces separated by &'s around to put the year first if you like.... then use the same MID and TEXT functions to find and pull out the time.